# how to create multiple databases in one single RDS using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

i am writing one cloudformation template in which i am creating one RDS instance and in launch configuration i am installing wordpress. now i want to create multiple databases in single RDS , What should be my Launch configuration look like.
here is my current launch configuration

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Wordpress: highly available and scalable template"
Parameters:
BlogID:
Description: "A unique identifier for your blog. For internal use only."
Type: String
AllowedPattern: "[A-Za-z0-9\\-]+"
ConstraintDescription: "Only letters, digits or dash allowed."
BlogTitle:
Description: "The title of the Wordpress blog."
Type: String
Default: "Just another Wordpress blog"
BlogAdminUsername:
Description: "A username for the Wordpress admin."
Type: String
Default: "admin"
BlogAdminPassword:
Description: "A password for the Wordpress admin."
Type: String
NoEcho: "true"
BlogAdminEMail:
Description: "The email address of the Wordpress admin."
Type: String
WebServerKeyName:
Description: "The key pair to establish a SSH connection to the web servers."
Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
WebServerInstanceType:
Description: "The instance type of web servers (e.g. t2.micro)."
Type: String
Default: "t2.micro"
DBServerInstanceType:
Description: "The instance type of database server (e.g. db.t2.micro)."
Type: String
Default: "db.t2.micro"

Mappings:
EC2RegionMap:
ap-northeast-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-cbf90ecb" }
ap-southeast-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-68d8e93a" }
ap-southeast-2: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-fd9cecc7" }
eu-central-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-a8221fb5" }
eu-west-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-a10897d6" }
sa-east-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-b52890a8" }
us-east-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-1ecae776" }
us-west-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-d114f295" }
us-west-2: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-e7527ed7" }

Resources:
VPC:
Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
Properties:
  CidrBlock: "172.31.0.0/16"
  EnableDnsHostnames: "true"

InternetGateway:
Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
Properties: {}

VPCGatewayAttachment:
Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
Properties:
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  InternetGatewayId: {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}

SubnetA:
Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
Properties:
  AvailabilityZone: {"Fn::Select": ["0", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]}
  CidrBlock: "172.31.38.0/24"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

SubnetB:
Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
Properties:
  AvailabilityZone: {"Fn::Select": ["1", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]}
  CidrBlock: "172.31.37.0/24"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

RouteTable:
Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
Properties:
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

RouteTableAssociationA:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetA"}
  RouteTableId: {"Ref": "RouteTable"}

RouteTableAssociationB:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetB"}
  RouteTableId: {"Ref": "RouteTable"}

RoutePublicNATToInternet:
Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
Properties:
  RouteTableId: {"Ref": "RouteTable"}
  DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
  GatewayId: {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
DependsOn: "VPCGatewayAttachment"

NetworkAcl:
Type: "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl"
Properties:
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

SubnetNetworkAclAssociationA:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetA"}
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}

SubnetNetworkAclAssociationB:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetB"}
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}

NetworkAclEntryIngress:
Type: "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry"
Properties:
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}
  RuleNumber: "100"
  Protocol: "-1"
  RuleAction: "allow"
  Egress: "false"
  CidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"

NetworkAclEntryEgress:
Type: "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry"
Properties:
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}
  RuleNumber: "100"
  Protocol: "-1"
  RuleAction: "allow"
  Egress: "true"
  CidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"

LoadBalancer:
Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
Properties:
  Subnets: [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]
  LoadBalancerName: {"Ref": "BlogID"}
  Listeners:
    - InstancePort: "80"
      InstanceProtocol: "HTTP"
      LoadBalancerPort: "80"
      Protocol: "HTTP"
  HealthCheck:
    HealthyThreshold: "2"
    Interval: "5"
    Target: "TCP:80"
    Timeout: "3"
    UnhealthyThreshold: "2"
  SecurityGroups: [{"Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}]
  Scheme: "internet-facing"
  CrossZone: "true"

  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
  Properties:
  GroupDescription: "wordpress-elb"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      FromPort: 80
      IpProtocol: "tcp"
      ToPort: 80

 WebServerSecurityGroup:
 Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
 Properties:
  GroupDescription: "wordpress-ec2"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      FromPort: 22
      IpProtocol: "tcp"
      ToPort: 22

    - FromPort: 80
      IpProtocol: "tcp"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: {"Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}
      ToPort: 80

  DatabaseSecurityGroup:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
  Properties:
  GroupDescription: "wordpress-rds"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: "tcp"
      FromPort: "3306"
      ToPort: "3306"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: {"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}

 Database:
 Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
  Properties:
  AllocatedStorage: "5"
  BackupRetentionPeriod: "0"
  DBInstanceClass: {"Ref": "DBServerInstanceType"}
  DBInstanceIdentifier: {"Ref": "BlogID"}
  DBName: "wordpress"
  Engine: "MySQL"
  MasterUsername: "wordpress"
  MasterUserPassword: "wordpress"
  VPCSecurityGroups: [{"Fn::GetAtt": ["DatabaseSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}]
  DBSubnetGroupName: {"Ref": "DBSubnetGroup"}
  MultiAZ: "true"
  StorageType: "gp2"

DBSubnetGroup:
Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
Properties:
  DBSubnetGroupDescription: "DB subnet group"
  SubnetIds: [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]



IAMUser:
Type: "AWS::IAM::User"
Properties:
  Path: "/"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: "UploadToS3"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: ["s3:*"]
            Resource:
              - {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref": "BlogID"} ,"/*"]]}

IAMAccessKey:
Type: "AWS::IAM::AccessKey"
Properties:
  UserName: {"Ref": "IAMUser"}

LaunchConfiguration:
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
Metadata:
  "AWS::CloudFormation::Init":
    config:
      packages:
        yum:
          "php": []
          "php-mysql": []
          "mysql": []
          "httpd": []
      sources: {"/var/www/html": "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.2.4.tar.gz"}
      files:
        "/root/config.sh":
          content:
            "Fn::Join":
              - ""
              - [
                  "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                  "cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'database_name_here'/'wordpress'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'username_here'/'wordpress'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'password_here'/'wordpress'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'localhost'/'", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["Database", "Endpoint.Address"]}, "'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "echo \"define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '", {"Ref": "IAMAccessKey"},"'); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "echo \"define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["IAMAccessKey", "SecretAccessKey"]},"'); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "echo \"define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true ); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "echo \"define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false ); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "chmod -R 777 wp-content/ \n",
                  "curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar core install --url=\"", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LoadBalancer", "DNSName"]}, "\" --title=\"", {"Ref": "BlogTitle"}, "\" --admin_user=\"", {"Ref": "BlogAdminUsername"}, "\" --admin_password=\"", {"Ref": "BlogAdminPassword"}, "\" --admin_email=\"", {"Ref": "BlogAdminEMail"}, "\" \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar plugin install --activate amazon-web-services \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar plugin install --activate amazon-s3-and-cloudfront \n",
                  "CHARCOUNT=`printf \"",{"Ref": "BlogID"} ,"\" | wc -c` \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar db query \"DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'tantan_wordpress_s3'; INSERT INTO wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES('tantan_wordpress_s3', 'a:15:{s:17:\\\"post_meta_version\\\";i:1;s:6:\\\"bucket\\\";s:", "$CHARCOUNT", ":\\\"", {"Ref": "BlogID"},"\\\";s:6:\\\"region\\\";s:0:\\\"\\\";s:6:\\\"domain\\\";s:9:\\\"subdomain\\\";s:7:\\\"expires\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:10:\\\"cloudfront\\\";s:0:\\\"\\\";s:13:\\\"object-prefix\\\";s:19:\\\"wp-content/uploads/\\\";s:10:\\\"copy-to-s3\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:13:\\\"serve-from-s3\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:17:\\\"remove-local-file\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:3:\\\"ssl\\\";s:7:\\\"request\\\";s:12:\\\"hidpi-images\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:17:\\\"object-versioning\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:21:\\\"use-yearmonth-folders\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:20:\\\"enable-object-prefix\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";}', 'yes');\" \n"
                ]
          mode: "000500"
          owner: "root"
          group: "root"

      commands:
        01_mv:
          command: "mv * ../"
          cwd: "/var/www/html/wordpress"
        02_config:
          command: "/root/config.sh"
          cwd: "/var/www/html"

      services:
        sysvinit:
          httpd:
            enabled: "true"
            ensureRunning: "true"

  Properties:
  ImageId: {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EC2RegionMap", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit"]}
  InstanceType: {"Ref": "WebServerInstanceType"}
  SecurityGroups: [{"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}]
  KeyName: {"Ref": "WebServerKeyName"}
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
  UserData:
    "Fn::Base64":
      "Fn::Join":
        - ""
        - [
            "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
            "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, " --resource LaunchConfiguration --region ", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, " --resource AutoScalingGroup --region ", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "\n"
          ]
  InstanceMonitoring: "true"

AutoScalingGroup:
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
Properties:
  LoadBalancerNames: [{"Ref": "LoadBalancer"}]
  LaunchConfigurationName: {"Ref": "LaunchConfiguration"}
  MinSize: "1"
  MaxSize: "2"
  DesiredCapacity: "1"
  Cooldown: "300"
  HealthCheckGracePeriod: "300"
  HealthCheckType: "ELB"
  VPCZoneIdentifier: [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]
  Tags:
    - PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
      Value: "wordpress"
      Key: "Name"



Outputs:
URL:
Value: {"Fn::Join": ["", ["http://", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LoadBalancer", "DNSName"]}]]}
Description: "URL to Wordpress"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported out of the box by CloudFormation.  However you can extend CF with [custom resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)

The approach would be:

1 - Create lambda function that would have access to RDS

2 - Add it to cloudformation and let it create additional databases/tables/users...

Comment: Thanks.. so is there any way i can create multiple databases and install wordpress on it ? apart from this

Comment: The thing is,  in order to do this , first you need to decide where the code that will trigger db creation should leave.  Then you would need to figure out how this code will get access to the DB ( credentials / firewalls ) . 
Another approach might be - pre-create your database in Docker with all the schema that you need and use Container Service + ECR to run it ( this has very obvious drawbacks such as managing DB yourself ).